# C++ cin.fail() question

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

When running the following code and enter a number, it works fine.
But when entering a letter, the program enters an infinite loop, displaying "Enter a number (0 to exit): cin failed."

My intent was to handle the cin fail case and prompt the user again.

```
int number;
do{
    cout << "Enter a number (0 to exit): ";
    cin >> number;
    if(cin.fail()){
        cout << "cin failed." << endl;
        cin.clear();
    }else{
        cout << "cin succeeded, " << number << " entered." << endl;
    }
}while(number != 0);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to clear the line from *cin*, using *cin.ignore*, in addition to clearing the stream state (which is what *cin.clear* does).

I have [several utility functions](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/tip/cpp/clinput.hpp) to make this easier (you'll be interested in *clearline* in particular, which clears the stream state and the current line) and almost an exact example of [what you want](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/tip/cpp/examples/clinput_loop.cpp).

Your code, more or less, using my *clearline*:

```
#include "clinput.hpp" // move my file to a location it can be used from

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  while (true) {
    cout << "Enter a number (0 to exit): ";
    int number;
    if (cin >> number) {
      cout << "Read " << number << '\n';
      if (number == 0) {
        break;
      }
    }
    else {
      if (cin.eof()) { // tested only *after* failed state
        cerr << "Input failed due to EOF, exiting.\n";
        return 1;
      }
      cerr << "Input failed, try again.\n";
      clearline(cin); // "cin >> clearline" is identical
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

There is still a potential issue here (fixed in my [clinput_loop.cpp](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/tip/cpp/examples/clinput_loop.cpp) with *blankline*), with leaving input in the buffer that will screw up later IO (see "42 abc" in the sample session).  Extracting the above code into a separate and self-contained function is left as an exercise for the reader, but here's a skeleton:

```
template<class Type, class Ch, class ChTr>
Type read(std::basic_istream<Ch,ChTr>& stream, Ch const* prompt) {
  Type value;
  // *try input here*
  if (could_not_get_input or more_of_line_left) {
    throw std::runtime_error("...");
  }
  return value;
}
template<class Type, class Ch, class ChTr>
void read_into(
  Type& value,
  std::basic_istream<Ch,ChTr>& stream,
  Ch const* prompt
) {
  value = read<Type>(stream, prompt);
}
```

Example use:

```
int n;
try {
  read_into(n, std::cin, "Enter a number: ");
}
catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
  //...
  raise;
}
cout << "Read " << n << '\n';
```

---

*clearline* function extracted for posterity, in case above links ever break (and slightly changed to make self-contained):

```
#include <istream>
#include <limits>

template<class C, class T>
std::basic_istream<C,T>& clearline(std::basic_istream<C,T>& s) {
  s.clear();
  s.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), s.widen('\n'))
  return s;
}
```

The template stuff is a bit confusing if you're not used to it, but it's not hard:

- *std::istream* is a typedef of `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >`
- *std::wistream* is a typedef of `std::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >`
- *widen* allows `'\n'` to become `L'\n'` as appropriate
- this code works for both of the common *char* and *wchar_t* cases, but also any compatible instantiation of *basic_istream*
- it's written to be called as `clearline(stream)` *or* `stream >> clearline`, compare to other manipulators like *std::endl*, *std::ws*, or *std::boolalpha*

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. One additional point is that I had to use both, cin.clear() and cin.ignore().

Comment: Yes, if you look at my clearline function (in clinput.hpp, and follow the code path), it calls both clear and ignore.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, with a great explanation of this small issue (but I'm not biased, eh? :P); however, I want to emphasize that **the iostream interface is horrible** (but the implementation is fast enough, contrary to popular complaint, once you add move semantics where needed) and **I wish there was a widespread, free (both beer and freedom), better alternative to recommend**.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you intended to do:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int i;
  do {
    if (cin.fail())
    {
      cin.ignore(255);
      cin.clear();
    }          
    cout << "Please enter an integer value: ";
    cin >> i;
  } while ( cin.fail() );
  cout << "The value you entered is " << i;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will always result in an infinite loop, as you neither modify the stream state nor the stream buffer once it enters a failed state.

Comment: "Always result.." if bad input is entered the first time, that is.

Comment: Heh, seems one learns something new each day... now it is correct? (no compiler at hand to test...)

Comment: Use the *numeric\_limits* form from my answer instead of a magic constant like 255, as the value I use is guaranteed to be interpreted as infinity by the stream.  You must also specify the newline delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example of cin.fail()
It will process input until a valid integer value is provided

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int j;
int i;

i = 0;
while (1) {
    i++;
    cin >> j;
    if (cin.fail()) return 0;
    cout << "Integer " << i << ": " << j << endl;
}
}
```

Input:

42 51 85 hello 85

Output:

Integer 1: 42

Integer 2: 51

Integer 3: 85

Comment: Please make an [edit] to explain what your code is doing.