# checking C++ string for an int: revised: clearing cin

Tags: c++, string, int, cin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to validate numeric input C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514420/how-to-validate-numeric-input-c)

How do you do the following:

```
while (iNumberOfPlayers <2 || iNumberOfPlayers >5)
{
    cout << "Enter number of players (1-4): ";
    cin >> iNumberOfPlayers;
    cin.clear();
    std::string s;
    cin >> s;
}
```

After looking at the loop I'm thrown in, it looks like `cin` isn't getting reset (if I put in x) `cin` reads X again as long as I'm in the `while` loop.  Guessing this is a buffer issue, any way to clear it?

I then tried:

```
while (iNumberOfPlayers <2 || iNumberOfPlayers >5)
{
    cout << "Enter number of players (1-4): ";
    cin >> iNumberOfPlayers;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}
```

which works except it reads everything 1 at a time.  If I put in "xyz" then the loop goes through 3 times before it stops to ask again.

Comment: you need to declare a, like `int a = 0;`

Comment: But if you declare `a` as an int, won't that make it very difficult for a to not be an int?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg int a = 0; cin << a;  if someone puts in something not an int (x for example) the whole program crashes.

Comment: Matt, your post title asks about testing whether a string can be tested to be an int, but your code has no strings in it. cin does not read things in as strings automatically. I just tested putting in bad data, and 'a' simply remains '0'.

Comment: @MattWestlake I suspected that. In which case @ThomasMcLeod's solution would crash your program... Then how have you declared `a`? That's a quite important thing to know.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032719/c-cin-fail-question

Comment: @Matt: No, if the program crashed because someone put non-numeric data in, it is because your code didn't check whether the input failed.  The *stream* will not *crash* when trying to parse invalid input.

Comment: @Matt: Looking at your edited question, you aren't using `cin.clear()` the way my answer shows.

Comment: called cin.clear(); and it just looped me still

Comment: @Matt: yeah, you're right that you also have to remove the trash from the buffer.  Look at my answer again.

Comment: getting a "no operator >> matches these operands" error on the last cin >> s statement

Comment: @MattWestlake - you need to keep the `cin >> a` inside the condition of the loop, not within the body of the loop ideally. I've updated my example to show this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the input is not valid, the fail bit is set on the stream.  The `!` operator used on a stream reads the fail bit (You could also use `(cin >> a).fail()` or `(cin >> a), cin.fail()`).

Then you just have to clear the fail bit before trying again.

```
while (!(cin >> a)) {
    // if (cin.eof()) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    cin.clear();
    std::string dummy;
    cin >> dummy; // throw away garbage.
    cout << "entered value is not a number";
}
```

Please note that if you're reading from non-interactive input, this would become an infinite loop.  So use some variation on the commented error-detection code.

Comment: That doesn't work, if I enter "hello" then it keeps repeating "value is not a number" because `cin.clear()` leaves the string in the input. You need to consume the non-`int` input too before repeating.

Comment: @Flexo: Your comment crossed my edit somewhere out in the internet.  Should work now.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky thing is that you need to consume any invalid input as failure to read doesn't consume the input. The simplest solution to this is to move the call to `operator >>` into the loop condition and then read up to the `\n` if it didn't mange to read an `int`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  int a;
  while (!(std::cin >> a) || (a < 2 || a > 5)) {
    std::cout << "Not an int, or wrong size, try again" << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear(); // Reset error and retry
    // Eat leftovers:
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }
}
```