# Loading multidimentional array from a file

Tags: c++

I wanna load a multidimentional array from a file, I have this code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
for (int r = 0; r < cols; r++)
{
    std::vector<int> row;
    for ( int c = 0 ; c < cols ; c++ )
    {
        int temp;
        if ( fin >> temp )
        {
            std::cout << temp;
            row.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    matrix.push_back(row);
}
```

Cols variable is fine, the nested loop is called 9 times if I have 3x3 array, so this works as expected...However it seems that the file cannot read single integer (`fin >> temp`). Fin is the file handler. What's wrong?

File content:

```
0 1 1
0 0 1
1 1 1
```

The whole code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo()
{
    std::string filename;
    std::cout << "Filename: ";
    std::cin >> filename;

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix;
    std::ifstream fin(filename);
    if(!fin) {
        std::cout << "Error";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::string line;
    int cols = 0;
    if(fin.is_open()){
        while(!fin.eof()){
            std::getline(fin,line);
            cols++;
        }
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < cols; r++)
    {
        std::vector<int> row;
        for ( int c = 0 ; c < cols ; c++ )
        {
            int temp;
            if ( fin >> temp )
            {
                std::cout << temp; // displays nothing
                row.push_back(temp);
            }
                        std::cout << temp; // displays some crap like -84343141
        }
        matrix.push_back(row);
    }
    std::cin >> filename; // to stop execution and see the results
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: The file is just a simple matrix where always columns = rows.

Comment: @DavidJashi: No it doesn't. It only reads the next integer.

Comment: @user2252786: Have you considered the possibility that `fin >> temp` fails? Your code should handle and report this.

Comment: So this should work...? I posted the whole function with a couple of tests, maybe this will give you some more tips.

Comment: Why is that loop there that reads the whole file first?

Comment: It counts the rows number to loop through the matrix later.

Comment: It's because `fin>>temp` fails and return `0`, so the `if` is false and you print uninicialized `temp` == that is why it prints crap.

Comment: I thought the comment "displays nothing" would suggest that I'm aware of that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032719/c-cin-fail-question look at this

Comment: What means " std::cin >> filename; // to stop execution and see the results"<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a first pass through the file to determine the size, but you are going to need to reopen the file after reading it the first time.  Otherwise, there is no data left in the file to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
fin.seekg (0, is.beg);
```

before the for cycle.

Because in

```
std::string line;
int cols = 0;
if(fin.is_open()){
    while(!fin.eof()){
        std::getline(fin,line);
        cols++;
    }
}
```

you will get the position in file at the `eof` and

```
if ( fin >> temp )
```

will always return false. That is why you need to set the position to the beginning of the file.

You can also replace

```
while(!fin.eof()){
        std::getline(fin,line);
        cols++;
    }
```

with easier

```
while(std::getline(fin,line)) cols++;
```

Answer (score 0):

First read the file, and calculate the number of rows and columns, then close the file.
Then again read the file, and now loop up to the calculated rows and columns