# My Quadratic equation code terminates when I enter a non integer value, how can I get it to loop properly?

Tags: c++, loops, math, quadratic

So I'm trying to get my Quadratic equation solution code to loop unless "0" is entered as any 1 of the quadratic coefficients. 
It works fine up until entering a non integer value, in which the program terminates.
I'd like the code to spit out a message prompting the user to enter a numerical value, and continue the loop as normal.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
for ( ; ; ){
float a, b, c, D, x1, x2, real, im;
cout << "Please enter the Quadratic Coefficients" << endl;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
if (cin.fail()){
    cout << "Error, please enter numerical values!" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
}
if ((a == 0) || (b == 0) || (c == 0)){
    break;
}
D = b*b - 4*a*c;
if (D < 0) {
    real = -b/(2*a); 
    im = sqrt(-D)/(2*a);
    cout << "Roots are Complex" << endl;
    cout << "x1 = " << real << "+" << im << "i" << endl;
    cout << "x2 = " << real << "-" << im << "i" << endl;

      }
else if (D == 0) {
x1 = (-b + sqrt(D)) / (2*a);
cout << "Real and Repeated Roots" << endl;      
cout << "x1 = " << x1 << endl;
   }
 else if (D > 0) 
{   
  x1 = (-b + sqrt(D)) / (2*a);

  x2 = (-b - sqrt(D)) / (2*a);

cout << "Real and Distinct Roots" << endl;
cout << "x1 = " << x1 << endl;
cout << "x2 = " << x2 << endl;
} } 

  return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: If there's a mismatch between the expected and actual input, then the `operator>>` function will stop immediately, and the non-matching input will not be extracted from the input buffer. I suggest you [read a whole line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and attempt to parse the input separately (perhaps with the help of e.g. [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)).

Comment: I'm confused as to what does not work. I can run it without any problem, including non-integer inputs like 1.0, 2.5 0.1, or mixed ones like 1, 2.5, 0.1. What inputs exactly don't work for you? Edit: nevermind, you mean non-numerical input, I see it now

Comment: if ((a == 0) || (b == 0) || (c == 0)){ break; => you miss some valid solutions here

Comment: @GeckoGeorge My bad, I meant non-numerical which of course is also non integer :)

Comment: @skeller You're correct, I should have replaced it with if ((a == 0)) {
break; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This solution here should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33284630/4070489).

`cin.fail()` set the input stream into a failed state, and you need to reset it manually to get it to do any further work. When you call `cin` again, it will notice its failed state and just go on, otherwise.

```
cin >> a >> b >> c;
if (cin.fail()){
  cin.clear(); //removes error flags
  cin.ignore(); //ignores last input
  cout << "Error, please enter numerical values!" << endl;
  cin >> a >> b >> c;
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks Gecko!
I've only recently started coding, so I'm still learning all the basics :)